# Search in static pages

Tags: search, asp-classic, static-content

I have an ASP web application which has pages with static content as well as dynamic content(data from database). I want to implement a search feature in the site.I Can do this with the dynamic data easily by framing the select query  based on the search keys and pull data from the tables,But i would like to know how can i implement the search with the static pages ?

Comment: I suggest that you include the ASP tag in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some sort of file indexing system such as [htdig](http://www.htdig.org/) or [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) to index your static content, then run your searches through that.

The main problem would be to present a unified search for both your static and dynamic content - I would simply push the dynamic content into the indexer (at least Lucene allows nicely for that) and use the same search system for both.